# How to get an equation out of glm result

Tags: r, glm

I've created a logistic regression with the `glm` function

```
mynewlogit <- glm(is_bad ~ ulmp_s_ratio + plmp_mac_all_60d +    plmp_est_mac_all_90d +      plmp_c_mac_all_90d +    lmp_s_ratio +   plmp_c_mac_hrsk_60d + ulmp_c_ycount +   pp_usr_lmp_count +  l2pp_pp_age_min +   lmp_c_ratio +   lmp_age_max +   lmp_age_avg                
           , data = rajsub, family = "binomial")
```

and I've got this result:

```
Coefficients:
     (Intercept)          ulmp_s_ratio      plmp_mac_all_60d  plmp_est_mac_all_90d  
      -1.6226917             1.8704011             0.1037387             0.1583566  
plmp_c_mac_all_90d           lmp_s_ratio   plmp_c_mac_hrsk_60d         ulmp_c_ycount  
      -0.1333490             1.0456631             1.1447296             1.6073142  
pp_usr_lmp_count       l2pp_pp_age_min           lmp_c_ratio           lmp_age_max  
       0.0404034             0.0000457            -0.1052236             0.0002902  
     lmp_age_avg  
      -0.0010493
```

How to present the outcome as an equation format, as:

`x = -1.6226917 + 1.8704011*ulmp_s_ratio ...`

Comment: `paste(coef(fit), names(coef(fit)), sep = ' * ', collapse = ' + ')`

Comment: @rawr, post as answer (or search for duplicates) ?