# Extracting model equation from glm function in R

Tags: r, equation, glm

I've made a logistic regression to combine two independent variables in R using `pROC` package and I obtain this:

```
summary(fit)

#Call: glm(formula = Case ~ X + Y, family = "binomial", data = data)

#Deviance Residuals: 
#  Min       1Q     Median     3Q      Max  
#-1.5751  -0.8277  -0.6095   1.0701   2.3080  

#Coefficients:
#             Estimate  Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#(Intercept) -0.153731   0.538511  -0.285 0.775281    
#X           -0.048843   0.012856  -3.799 0.000145 ***
#Y            0.028364   0.009077   3.125 0.001780 ** 
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

#Null deviance: 287.44  on 241  degrees of freedom
#Residual deviance: 260.34  on 239  degrees of freedom
#AIC: 266.34

#Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

fit

#Call:  glm(formula = Case ~ X + Y, family = "binomial", data = data)

#Coefficients:
#  (Intercept)       X            Y  
#   -0.15373     -0.04884      0.02836  

#Degrees of Freedom: 241 Total (i.e. Null);  239 Residual
#Null Deviance:      287.4 
#Residual Deviance:  260.3        AIC: 266.3
```

Now I need to extract some information from this data, but I'm not sure how to do it.

First, I need the model equation: suppose that fit is a combined predictor called `CP`, could it be `CP = -0.15 - 0.05X + 0.03Y` ?

Then, the resulting combined predictor from the regression should may present a median value, so that I can compare median from the two groups Case and Controls which I used to make the regression ( in other words, my `X` and `Y` variables are `N` dimensional with `N = N1 + N2`, where `N1` = Number of Controls, for which `Case=0`, and `N2` = Number of Cases, for which `Case=1`).

I hope to have explained everything.

Comment: Consider moving your question to http://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sick, i thought i've posted there. How can i move? Just a copy paste?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121853/how-to-get-an-equation-out-of-glm-result?rq=1

Comment: I've  looked that answer, that i've previously not found, but i have another point in the question so i guess it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I see you re-posted the question on the Data Science SE, thanks.  I think you should close this one here ... Can't do it myself.